# WebViewClient is redirecting even though there is no URL

Tags: android

I used the below code to show my Twitter Login page.

For the first time, it is calling `public void onPageStarted----->public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` and after I login it is redirecting url and calling `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. So the flow looks like:

1. `onPageStarted`
2. `onPageFinished`
3. `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

But when I Logout and comes for second time, I expect the same flow like the above but the flow changed to:

1. `onPageStarted`
2. `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`
3. `onPageFinished`

I didn't understand why this changed, and why it is calling `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` even though there is no URL is there before.

I printed the webviews url, it is `null` but still why it is redirecting to this method.

```
    private class TwitterWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Redirecting URL " + url);

                if (url.startsWith(TwitterApp.CALLBACK_URL)) {
                    mListener.onComplete(url);
                    Log.e("starts","starts with");
                    TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();

                    return true;
                }  else if (url.startsWith("authorize")) {

                    Log.e("authorize","authorization");
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Page error: " + description);

                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

                mListener.onError(description);

                TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                Log.e("page started in",url);
                Log.d(TAG, "Loading URL: " + url);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                mSpinner.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                String title = mWebView.getTitle();
                if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
                    Log.e("title","settitle");
                    mTitle.setText(title);
                }
                mSpinner.dismiss();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Yes,But I think something is left in webview, so the secondtime it is directly calling .......... public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) this method.Do I need to remove anything in Webview?

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug on shouldOverrideUrlLoading on Android < 3.0, I have this code to get twitter oauth:

```
authorizationWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                    // 11 = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB (Android 3.0)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {

                        // According to this page:
                        //
                        // http://www.catchingtales.com/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-and-redirect/416/
                        //
                        // shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is not called for redirects on
                        // Android earlier than 3.0, so call the method manually.
                        //
                        // The implementation of shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returns
                        // true only when the URL starts with the callback URL and
                        // dummyCallbackUrl is true.

                        if (shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)) {
                            view.stopLoading();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    // If the url is the same host, not override (api.twitter.com)
                    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(Uri.parse(Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL).getHost())) {

                        return false;

                    } else if (url.startsWith(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)) {

                        // Retrieve access token in vase of oauth_verifier
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

                        twitterOauth.retrieveAccessToken(verifier, MainActivity.this);

                        return true;

                    }

                    // If the user clicks in this webview on a link of other host, redirect to a browser.
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);

                    return true;

                }

            });
```

Hope this code help you.